# Digitar número novamente se for repetido

Tags: pascal

Peciso fazer um programa em que o usuário digite 5 números. Caso um desses números seja repetido, ele deve pedir para que o usuário digite novamente outro número, porém qualquer número que eu digito aparece que é repetido. Meu código:

```
   program numero_repetido;
    var
       numero: array [1..5] of integer;
       i: integer;
         ii: integer;
       valoratual:integer;
    begin
    ii:= 1;
    i:=1;
    for i:= 1 to 5 do
        begin
            if i > 0 then
            begin
             Write('Digite um número inteiro: ');
             read(numero[i]);
             
             valoratual:= numero[i];
             
                for ii:=1 to 5 do 
                    begin
                        if valoratual = numero[ii] then
                            begin;
                                Write('Número já existe, digite outro: ');
                                i:=i-1;
                                                        
                            end;
                    end;
            end
            else
            begin
                Write('Digite um número inteirooo: ');
                read(numero[i]);
            end;            
        end;
     
    for i:= 1 to 5 do
        begin
            writeLN(numero[i]);
        end;
 
   END.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perceba que você pega o número atual digitado:

```
valoratual:= numero[i];
```

E em seu `for` que verifica se o número já existe, você compara com o item que acabou de ser digitado, pois seu `for` varre o array por completo:

```
for ii := 1 to 5 do 
begin
    if valoratual = numero[ii] then
    begin;
        Write('Número já existe, digite outro: ');
        i:=i-1;
    end;
end;
```

---

Você pode alterar o seu segundo `for`, para que ele vá de `1` até o `i - 1`, pois seria até a posição anterior a que você está:

```
for ii := 1 to ( i - 1 ) do 
begin
    if valoratual = numero[ii] then
    begin;
        Write('Número já existe, digite outro: ');
        i := i-1;
    end;
end;
```

---

Isso corrigirá a questão dos números serem sempre iguais... Mas seu código *não compila no Free Pascal*... pois no seu exemplo, você altera a variável `i` dentro do `for` e isso não é permitido.

Caso você venha a ter esse problema, você pode alterar um pouco mais o código, veja o exemplo:

```
program numero_repetido;
var
    numero: array [1..5] of integer;
    i: integer;
    ii: integer;
    valoratual: integer;
    repetido: boolean;
begin
    ii := 1;
    i := 1;

    for i := 1 to 5 do
    begin
        repetido := true;

        while repetido do
        begin
            writeLn('Digite um número inteiro: ');
            read(numero[i]);
            valoratual := numero[i];
            repetido := false;

            for ii := 1 to (i - 1) do 
            begin
                if valoratual = numero[ii] then
                begin;
                    writeLn('Número já existe, digite outro!');
                    repetido := true;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;

    writeLn('Números digitados:');

    for i:= 1 to 5 do
    begin
        writeLn(numero[i]);
    end;
end.
```

Nesse exemplo eu passei a utilizar o `while` como forma de manter o usuário dentro do loop até que digite um número válido.

> Veja online: http://tpcg.io/1AUKL6zd

Answer (score 1):

No segundo bloco for você está comparando o valor do array com os indices iguais (i = 1 e ii = 1), isto é, sempre será igual. Você está comparando um valor com ele mesmo.

Você pode corrigir solicitando o primeiro valor fora do loop de teste, solicitar o restantes dos valores com for i:=2..5 e depois comparar os valores seguintes com um loop for ii:=1..i-1

Além disso, seu bloco else nunca será executado, pois você condicionou seu loop for com valores de 1 a 5 (sempre maior que 0).